# Why is this Element not Found?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, settings

I added code to my Windows Store App project to utilize the Settings pane for my app's custom settings. I based this code on what is in Adam Nathan's book "Windows 8 Apps with XAML and C#", beginning on p. 503.

I have this code in App.xaml.cs:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;
    UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;
}

private void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs spcreArgs)
{
    spcreArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand(1, "App Bar Color", OnSettingsCommand));
    spcreArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand(2, "Visit Types to Display", OnSettingsCommand));
    spcreArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand(3, "Display Current Location", OnSettingsCommand));
    spcreArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand(4, "Set Home Base", OnSettingsCommand));
}

private void OnSettingsCommand(Windows.UI.Popups.IUICommand command)
{
    int id = (int) command.Id;
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            //Bla => I think this is where I need to add "this.[custom settings pane (user control) name].Show(command)
            break;
        case 2:
            //Bla
            break;
        case 3:
            //Bla
            break;
        case 4:
            //Bla
            break;
    }
}
```

...but it fails on the "*SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;*" line with:

```
System.Exception was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147023728
  Message=Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
  Source=Windows.UI
  StackTrace:
       at Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView()
       at Visits.App..ctor()
       at Visits.Program.<Main>b__0(ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams p)
  InnerException:
```

When I view the detailed exception info, I see:

[image]

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView()` is throwing an exception because you're calling it too early. You are configuring the settings for a specific view, but in the application constructor there is no view yet, hence `Element not found`.

Move you code to a page without changing anything and it will work:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;
}

private void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs spcreArgs)
{
    spcreArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand(1, "App Bar Color", OnSettingsCommand));
    spcreArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand(2, "Visit Types to Display", OnSettingsCommand));
    spcreArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand(3, "Display Current Location", OnSettingsCommand));
    spcreArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand(4, "Set Home Base", OnSettingsCommand));
}

private void OnSettingsCommand(Windows.UI.Popups.IUICommand command)
{
    int id = (int)command.Id;
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            //Bla => I think this is where I need to add "this.[custom settings pane (user control) name].Show(command)
            break;
        case 2:
            //Bla
            break;
        case 3:
            //Bla
            break;
        case 4:
            //Bla
            break;
    }
}
```