# How can I reference my UserControls to display them on the Settings pane?

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, settings

I'm trying to implement custom settings for my Windows Store app. I have User Controls, such as UserControlAppBarColors.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControlAppBarColor"
    x:Class="Visits.UserControlAppBarColors"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Popup x:Name="popupAppBarColors" IsLightDismissEnabled="True" 
Closed="PopupAppBarColors_OnClosed" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="345">
        <Popup.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <PaneThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Popup.Transitions>
    <Grid Name="gridAppBarColors" Background="Brown" Width="345">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="21,30,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Content="Go Back" Click="BackButton_Click" />
                    <TextBlock Text="App Bar Color" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="144" 
FontWeight="Normal" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Margin="-2,-2,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="13,0,0,0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Canvas Background="Aqua" Width="20" Height="20" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="CanvasColor_Tapped"></Canvas>
                        <TextBlock Text="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Canvas Background="Black" Width="20" Height="20" 
VerticalAlignment="Center"></Canvas>
                        <TextBlock Text="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    . . .
```

Based on Adam Nathan's book , on pages 503-507, I've added this code to App.xaml.cs:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;
}

private void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs 
spcreArgs)
{
    spcreArgs.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand(1, "App Bar Color", 
OnSettingsCommand));
    . . .
}

// Finish this; see Nathan p. 504-507
private void OnSettingsCommand(Windows.UI.Popups.IUICommand command)
{
    int id = (int) command.Id;
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            break;
        . . .
    }
}
```

...and this to MainPage.xaml (showing in context, after the "Grid" declaration):

```
. . .
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <!--next four lines from Nathan p. 506-->
<local:UserControlAppBarColors x:Name="appBarColors" />
. . .
```

...but in the switch statement in App.xaml.cs none of the following work - all say, "Cannot resolve symbol":

```
        // Failure 1:
        case 1:
            this.appBarColors.Show(command); // name from MainPage.xaml
            break;

        // Failure 2:
        case 1:
            this.userControlAppBarColor.Show(command); // name of user control from 
UserControlAppBarColors.xaml
            break;

        // Failure 3:
        case 1:
            this.popupAppBarColors.Show(command); // name of user control's popup from 
UserControlAppBarColors.xaml
            break;
```

What am I misunderstanding or miscoding here?

### UPDATE

It turns out that I had the first section of code in the wrong place: instead of App.xaml.cs, it needs to be in MainPage.xaml.cs - now it works!

BTW, my first idea (appBarColors.Show(command)) is the one that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damir Arh gave the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204707/why-is-this-element-not-found)

It turns out that I had the first section of code in the wrong place: instead of App.xaml.cs, it needs to be in MainPage.xaml.cs - now it works!

BTW, my first idea (appBarColors.Show(command)) is the one that works.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `case 1:` for all the case labels in the `switch` construct.
Use `case 2:` or appropriate label. Case labels have to be unique.

Comment: No, those are just the examples of all the things I tried; I tried the first, commented it out, tried the second, etc.

Comment: Yea, it looks already a bit strange, but everyone has a bad day now and them. I checked further, but the only thing I saw was that `Show()` is not a valid function of the user control. It is a valid member of the form, but it has no parameter; `Show(command)` is invalid. Are you missing your own `Show()` implementations? I don't know the book, maybe it is coded there, but not sure.